# Incrementer not working inside string replace

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm attempting to read a line from a file (csv header) and create a column list that prepends "c[num]_" in front of each column with this code:

```
int colCount=0;
string line = "col1,col2,col3,col4,col5";
string ColumnList = "([" + (++colCount).ToString() + "_" + line.Replace(",", "],[c" + (++colCount).ToString() + "_") + "]";
```

I know it's not elegant, but I'm also not sure why my colCount variable doesn't increment inside the replace??  It results with a string like:

```
([c0_col1],[c1_col2],[c1_col3],[c1_col4],[c1_col5])
```

The counter increments the first time and then not again inside the replace.  Any insights? I think it might be better written with a Regex ReplaceEvaluator but I haven't been able to piece that together yet either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paramter of the `Replace` method is string, and the expression you've entered there is just a string. The count will always be `2`. It's not a `Func`, it a `string`.

You can use the following Linq to easily achieve the conversion you'd like:

```
string ColumnList = string.Join(",", line.Split(',').Select((s, i) => $"[c{i + 1}_{s}]"));
```

Comment: Hadn't even though to look into Linq yet.  This appears to be working and something I can adapt though.  Appreciate it.